# regex change to detetct more pre-domain

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expression and trying to learn changing the following regex, was wondering if you can help me.

The following will detect for me the links such as :

```
<http://www.ijs.si/software/delet.obo#VO_Broker>
```

regex:

```
<(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})
```

How do I change the same regex so it can also detect for me

```
<http://kt.ijs.si/software/delet.obo#VO_Broker>
```

Comment: Your pattern doesn't match either of your links. When something ends up being this complex there's a good chance a simpler method exists

Comment: Yeah, I agree... can you update your question to clarify what you are actually trying to capture?  Is it all URLs, specific URLs?

Comment: I edited and now it matches. I am not sure but my understanding is that it is trying to capture all URLs

Answer (score 0):

I use the following regex to check for urls:

```
(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-\w+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-\w+&@#\/%=~_|])
```

Works fine and is a lot simpler.